# Next/image is generating an Element type is invalid error

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use the next/image to render an svg image. However whenever I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ImagePage`
```

The source code for ImagePage:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Paper } from '@mui/material';

import Img from '../../images/image.svg';

const ImagePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Paper>
                <Image src={Img} />
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImagePage;
```

If I put any other component between the div tags I do not see this error. The path to the image is correct.

Is there a different way I can render the image that doesn't cause this error to be thrown?

Comment: The documentation says the src prop expects a string. Does `<Image src="../../images/image.svg" />` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem I was having was that the import for Image was coming in as an object. The object had a key called default, which was the actual Image implementation. In order to access the Image, I had to update the tag to:

```
<Image.default src={'/image.svg'} />
```

The import was behaving this way because of the following line in my package.json:

```
"type": "module",
```

Once I took this out, I was able to access the Image:

```
<Image src={'/image.svg'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete [Gan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248203/16996769) answer, you need to provide a path that corresponds to the public folder. That's the only folder you can put your assets in. Furthermore, you can use a forward slash to directly access the public folder. So considering that your asset is already in the public directory under the images folder, use this:

```js
<Image src={`/images/image.svg`} alt='Icon' width={32} height={32}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute takes a string value in the Image component. Seems there is nothing wrong with your source code. However, your import section represents an object rather than a path, which might be conflicting with an object name or some reserved component name.

So, you need to provide an SVG path instead of an imported object. It is supposed to be

```
<Image src={`../../images/image.svg`} alt='Icon' width={32} height={32}/>
```

PS: The Image component requires `alt`, `width` and `height`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll try the answer and if it works, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I put the exact Image tag that's in this answer in the code and I'm still getting the same error. If I take out the Image tag then the problem goes away. I also tried <Image /> and it's still getting the same error. I'm not sure what's causing the error since there aren't any objects inside of the image tag.

Comment: So I add a console.log on the Image type itself and sure enough it's an object. That's what I think the error is referring to. It looks like there's something wrong with the import to where it's not getting the react component of Image.

Comment: Seems like you are getting closer to the solution. I suspect your packages have some causes. Please check your dependencies (in the package.json) and disable some of them temporarily and test. Hopefully, you'll find some clues.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I took a look at the keys in the object I was getting and  got the following keys: default and unstable_getImgProps. I tried using the default by updating the Image tag to: <Image.default src='/Lock.svg' alt='Icon' width={32} height={32}/> and the image rendered to the screen. Any ideas why the import is coming in this way?